# Change the visible position of ROWs of ultragrid programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, ultrawingrid

I have an ultragrid with an unbound Boolean column that i had named it "Select".

user can select and deselect a row by checked or unchecked the "Select" cell of that row.

but if the number of the grid rows are very much, its difficult for the user to find all of selected rows.

So i want to send the selected rows to the top of the grid just after the user select them.
but i could not found any property that can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found my solution myself:

```
private void ultraGrid1_AfterCellUpdate(object sender, CellEventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (e.Cell.Column.Key == "Select" && Convert.ToBoolean(e.Cell.Value))  
            {  
                ultraGrid1.Rows.Move(e.Cell.Row, newPosition);  
            }  
        }
```

Comment: You can use `e.Cell.Row.ParentCollection` instead of `ultraGrid1.Rows` to also make this work with subrows (as long as you are moving the row to a new position under the same parent).